# Django implement search filter with MySql Db

Tags: python, django

I want to search from keywords field in database that match whole word not character in that like:

```
When my search term = "service"
Then i get the result = ["Car service", "cab service"]

And when my search term = "vice"
Then also my result = ["Car service", "cab service"], but it should = []
```

Here is my code:

```
def search_service_view(request):
query_string = request.data['query'].split(' ')
category = ServiceCategory.objects.filter(
    reduce(operator.or_, (Q(keywords__icontains=query) for query in query_string)))
serializer = ServiceCategorySerializer(category, many=True, read_only=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: `icontains` does exactly what you don't want so maybe you should find a way to search using regular expressions.

Comment: I know that, but how would i do it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#regex

Comment: Where would i place my query sting in this  = Entry.objects.get(title__regex=r'^(An?|The) +')

Comment: somewhat like this `ServiceCategory.objects.filter(keywords__regex=r'\bservice\b')`

Comment: It does not give result